# Add select points to colored bspline

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggforce

Continuing on from my previous bspline [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49739450/chop-up-bsplines-and-color-them/49741399?noredirect=1#comment86521015_49741399)

If this is my curve:

```
data <- tibble (
  x = c(10, 15, 17, 17, 20, 22, 22, 23, 25, 25, 27, 29),
  y = c(5, 7, 4, 4, 0, 5, 5, 6, 5, 5, 4, 5.5),
  g = c("A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "C", "C", "C", "D","D","D"),
  pt = c(0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1)
)

ggplot(data) + 
  stat_bspline2(aes(x=x, y=y, color = ..group.., group = g), size = 4, n = 300, geom = "bspline0") +
  scale_color_gradientn(colours = c("red", "pink", "green", "white"), guide = F)
```

How do I add dots to selected points on the curve?

Here's how not to do it:

```
ggplot(data) + 
  stat_bspline2(aes(x=x, y=y, color = ..group.., group = g), size = 4, n = 300, geom = "bspline0") +
  scale_color_gradientn(colours = c("red", "pink", "green", "white"), guide = F) +
  stat_bspline2(data = pt, aes(x = x, y = x, color = ..group.., group = pt), n = 12, geom = "point", size = 9)
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't perfect, but it works. Add some columns with the positions of the points you want (I'm assuming that if pt = 1, you want the point plotted)

```
data <- data %>%
    mutate(pt_x = ifelse(pt == 1, x, NA),
           pt_y = ifelse(pt == 1, y, NA))

ggplot(data) + 
    stat_bspline2(aes(x=x, y=y, color = ..group.., group = g), size = 4, n = 300, geom = "bspline0") +
    scale_color_gradientn(colours = c("red", "pink", "green", "white"), guide = F) +
    geom_point(aes(pt_x, pt_y))
```

Comment: Your assumption is correct. Thank-you for your guidance.